# MySQL: add element to result array

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way I can add an integer to each entry in the result array returned from an SQL query?

For example a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

Is there anything I can add to that statement to add a column to the resulting array with a specified integer in it?

Comment: Something like `SELECT *, 1 AS newCol FROM mytable` ;).

Comment: Thanks, does newCol need to be added as a column in the table?

Comment: No you don't need to add a new column to your table that's just an alias ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS newCol 
FROM mytable
```

You can also set your specific type of your field by using [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) like this:

```
SELECT *, CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(4,2)) As newCol
FROM mytable
```